# How to perform many Mann-Whitney tests conditionally based on the value within a column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I want to create a function (or a way to perform the test in one-go) that does Mann Whitney test. I want to analyze logSG values between 2 different CC conditions within the same Time. So for following dataframe, I want 3 p-values that correspond to each Time.

My sample dataframe:

```
structure(list(Time = c("30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", 
"30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "60", "60", "60", "60", "60", 
"60", "60", "60", "60", "60", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", 
"90", "90", "90"), CC = c("Scramble", "Scramble", "Scramble", 
"Scramble", "Scramble", "Scramble", "Scramble", "Scramble", "KD", 
"KD", "KD", "KD", "KD", "Scramble", "Scramble", "Scramble", "Scramble", 
"Scramble", "KD", "KD", "KD", "KD", "KD", "Scramble", "Scramble", 
"Scramble", "Scramble", "KD", "KD", "KD", "KD", "KD"), logSG = c(0, 
6.29469069760774, 6.97548510669835, 0, 0, 5.6529880324294, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 5.84818081635987, 0, 6.33960454566506, 0.410736902037262, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0294484401648161, 0, 1.03061195077248, -1.30321174424293, 
-1.25902114646857, 0, 0, 0.787059500696643, 3.54611686297603, 
0, 0, -0.297732408305282, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7f9b120204e0>)
```

I tried following for every time point:

```
e <- result[result$Time == 30,]
wilcox.test(SG ~ CC, data=e)
```

This is clunky and inefficient.

Or, I'm having trouble getting this to work:

```
t <- result %>% group_by(Time) %>% do(te=wilcox.test(logSG ~ CC))
```

If possible, I'd like to learn how to do this using both `dplyr` and `m/s/apply`.

References: [link](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/polopoly_fs/1.714563!/file/stcp-karadimitriou-MannWhitR.pdf) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383371/grouped-t-test-with-more-than-two-levels-in-grouping-factor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are using `do`, then specify the `data`

```
library(dplyr)
result %>%
     group_by(Time) %>%
     do(te=wilcox.test(logSG ~ CC, data = .))
```

---

Or using `map` on `nest`ed dataset

```
library(purrr)
result %>%
   group_by(Time) %>%
   nest %>%
   mutate(te = map(data, ~ wilcox.test(logSG ~ CC, data = .x) ))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you think 'dplyr' is a better way to go rather than using 'sapply' or something similar?

Comment: @CeC  As it is a group by operation, the `tidyverse` approach would be more easier to understand.  But you can also do this in `base R` after `split`ting i.e. `lapply(split(result, result$Time), function(dat) wilcox.test(logSG ~ CC, data = dat))`

Comment: I didn't think to use ```split```. Thank you for your help!